# Problem exporting from blender to ue5

Tags: export, unreal-engine

why when I try to export a mesh to ue5 from blender I get this massage: "Wood-Stairs has some nearly zero tangents which can create some issues.(Tolerance of 1E-4)"
And:
"Wood-Stairs has some nearly zero bi-normals which can create some issues. (Tolerance of 1E-4)"
And I can see through the mesh
[image]

[image]